# Appending the input of my methods to an array-list (methods passed as parameter to the constructor of my class)

Tags: java

I have a class called faculty with methods to add properties of the  faculty .I have implimented the methods askModel() askSerial() and passed them  as paramaters to  the constructor of my box.java.... The question is How can I make my properties be appended to the List i have ceated in my Main.

Edit : with the question above I was trying to archive the code below . It works now as expected.

```
   package first_;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class faculty extends person {

    double salary;
    String title;
    double yearsINservice;
    public faculty(){
     super();
     this.salary = salary;
     this.title = title;
     this.yearsINservice = yearsINservice;
     }



     /*Name Age is an abstract Method from superClass Person*/
        public void nameAge(){
        setFirstName(scanfirstName());
        setLastName(scanlastName());
        setAge(scanage());
        setSalary(scansalary());
        setTitle(scantitle());
        setYearsINservice(scanyearsINservice());
    }

     /*Address is a SuperClass extended by Abstract class Person*/
        public void addressparamaters(){
              setHouseNum(scnhouseNum());
              setStreetName(scnstreeetName());
              setCity(scnCity());
              setState(scnState());
              setZip(scnZip());
          }  
     /*SETTERS AND GETTERS */
    public double getSalary() {return salary;}
    public void setSalary(double salary) {this.salary = salary;}
    public String getTitle() {return title;}
    public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}
    public double getYearsINservice() { return yearsINservice;}
    public void setYearsINservice(double yearsINservice) {this.yearsINservice = yearsINservice;}






    public int scansalary(){
        int salary;

        System.out.println("Please Enter The Monthly Salary");
        salary = scan.nextInt();

              return salary;
    }


    public String scantitle(){
        String title = "";

        System.out.println("Please Enter The Title");
        title = scan.next();

              return title;
    }

    public double scanyearsINservice(){
        double yearsINservice = 0;

       System.out.println("Please Enter The Number of Years in Service");
       salary = scan.nextDouble();

                return yearsINservice;
    }

    public String scanfirstName(){

        String firstname = "";

        System.out.println("Please Enter First Name");

    boolean notDone = true;
    while(true){
    try{
       firstname = scan.next();
    break;
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Please a valid Name format");
    continue;
         }
         }
           return firstname;
    }

    public String scanlastName(){
        String lastname = "";

        System.out.println("Please Enter Last Name");
        lastname = scan.next();
          return lastname;
    }

    public double scanage(){

        double age= 0 ;

    System.out.println("Please Enter Age");
    boolean notDone = true;
    while(notDone) {
    try{
        age = scan.nextDouble();
        break;

    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      scan.nextLine();
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      System.out.println("Please a valid age format");
      continue;
    }

    }
    return age;
    }
    @Override
    public String toSTring() {
         return  "\n First Name:" + " " + firstName +
                 "\n Last Name : " +"  "+ lastName +
                 "\n Age : " +"  "+ age + 
                 "\n Salary : " + "   " + salary +
                 "\n Title : " + "  "+ title + 
                 "\n yearsINservice : " +"  "+ yearsINservice +
                 "\n HOUSE NUMBER:" + " " + houseNum +
                 "\nStreet Name : " +"  "+ streetName +
                 "\nCity : " +"  "+ City +  
                 "\n State: " +"  "+ State + 
                 "\n Zip: " +"  "+ zip; 

                 }

}
```

Comment: Do you want to mix data types in that list of properties? Why not just have a list of boxes? And, are you wondering how to access fields from  a `Box` object?

Comment: Am I wrong or Box is abstract and he is do a `new Box()`?

Comment: @StackUnderFlow How about `box.serialNum` and so on?

Comment: @bellabax . Box is abstract because eventually I am going to create different subclasses  for different types of boxes(which will extend Box.java).

Comment: OK, but `Box box= new  Box();` with `Box` abstract, in your code, doesn't work...

Comment: @ Keyser I did box.serielNum() to see if the methods are accessible and yes they are acceible . but how can I make what is inputted there be added to Boxlist.  It is like saying list.add("something")   but here I have a method of my own and not sure how to go about interconnecting the two.

Comment: @bellabax  I know we can not instantiate object of Abstract class .. this is there because i changed my class to abstract and forgot this one there .... and this is not the problem anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations about your program:

All you have to do is add the `box` object to the list:

```
boxList.add(box);
```

Once there, you can access the array list entries to get all the properties of each box in it. Please check [the Java API for `ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Now, I have to tell you: You are mixing in your `Box` class everithing: Object attributes and User interface. I recommend you take out the scanner of the `Box` class, and use your `main` method to deal with the user input. You can write `setXXX()`  methods in your `Box` class to set the attribute values from an external piece of code:

```
public class Box {
    private String type;
    private String model;
    private String serialNum;

    public Box() {
        // A simple constructor that does nothing
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    // And so on
}
```

And in your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Box> boxList = new  ArrayList<Box>();
    Box box = new Box(); // Uses the `dummy` constructor
    System.out.println("Box type?\t");
    box.setType(input.next());
    System.out.println("Box model?\t");
    box.setModel(input.next());
    // And so on
    boxList.add(box);
    // Add as many boxes as you need
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Barranka , That is exactlly what I needed.

Comment: @StackUnderFlow By the way, your original `TestList` class duplicates the declaration of the `boxList` object... If you won't use (or need) the `boxList` outside the `TestList` class, remove the declaration outside the `main` method. (And also by the way, if it works, accept it ;) )

Comment: this was supposed to be commented out, but thanks for pointing that out.